# How to create torrent files using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create torrent files with a Firefox extension written using javascript. 
Torrent file creators are currently available as desktop applications in anything but javascript.
May be it is also possible to find a decent torrent file spec in java, as azurious, an open source p2p client, is written in java.
Can somebody please give me hints, or maybe some specs, to achieve it using javascript.

Comment: Java != Javascript. 

http://www.dannyg.com/ref/javavsjavascript.html

Comment: You cant create torrent files using javascript. You can use Java to do it.

Comment: yaep but If we give all previlages to javascript shouldn't it be possible.

Comment: I haven't ever said java=javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is normally run within a browser in a "sandboxed" environment, where it can't for example create files. If you want to use Javascript in a standalone environment, such as [jslibs](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/), that's a very different proposition, and creating files becomes possible. So is your issue with Javascript per se, as your question and tagging indicate, or with the sandboxing browsers typically perform on it?

Comment: Hi,
I am developing firefox extension. As a feature i want to provide torrent file creator. 
So i think, i will have all the privilages for creating files. 
can you please tell me where to get started i.e. creating files and all is ok but what actually present in torrent and how to implement it in javascript. 
Thanks

Comment: I believe it's possible to write files in Firefox extensions, yes (never done it myself). Torrent files are complicated but well specified, see sections 6 and 7 in http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Metainfo_File_Structure ; I don't know of existing Javascript libraries to help with that. What information do you start from -- eg do you have the SHA1 values for the various pieces or do you have to compute them yourself?